# Does the Book of Exalted Deeds' Enlightened Magic benefit apply to cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, cantrips, artifacts

The artifact [*Book of Exalted Deeds*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/book-of-exalted-deeds) (DMG, p. 222) has the following attribute:

> ***Enlightened Magic.*** Once you've read and studied the book, any spell slot you expend to cast a cleric or paladin spell counts as a spell slot of one level higher.

How does this work for cantrips, since there is no real level to increase it too? Does the cantrip just do extra damage as if it were cast by a higher-level character?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 29):

#### Cantrips don't use spell slots so the Enlightened Magic property of the Book of Exalted Deeds has no effect on them.

Page 201 of the PHB states:

> A cantrip is a spell that can be cast at will, **without using a spell slot...**

Since the Enlightened Magic property specifically says that:

> any **spell slot** you expend to cast a cleric or paladin spell counts as a spell slot of one level higher

then any spell cast *without* using a spell slot is unaffected.